# constructing efficient error code mapper in Django filters or middlewares?

Tags: django, jax-rs, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I am in the process of migrating my code from `JAX-RS` rest service to `Django-Rest Framework`. One nice feature that JAX-RS provides is `Exception Mapper` where different exceptions thrown by various components could be mapped to a generic map one.

One example is that an API call to authenticate user can fail for the following reasons:

1. username is wrong -- Error code 1000
2. Password is wrong -- Error code 1001
3. database is down - Error code 1002

I might want to map "1000" and "1001" into one generic code "5325" which the front-end/device team can interpret as "username and password did not match"

In JAX-RS mapping is done at REST layer. In fact, I can throw one kind of exception and map that to error code to be sent in response.

How can I achieve the same in Django?

For example:

```
def process_checkout(request):
    //
    if request.user.is_authenticated :
        //then process checkout
    else:
      raise userNotAuthenticatedError
```

Now, the `middleware` should map "userNotAuthenticatedError" to an error-code, construct a JSON response such as `{50000 :"user not authenticated"}` and send the response to client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django REST Framework handles validation exceptions, as well as other exception, through a [central exception handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/). In Django REST Framework 3.0, `ValidationError` exceptions make their way up to the exception handler, so you can relay them through there. In Django REST Framework 2.4, validation error handling is done on the serializer level, and you would have to trigger your errors there.

You would need to define your exception handler in a file (`my.app.views`) and [set up the handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) in your Django settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my.app.views.exception_handler'
}
```

You will need to make sure to set up the exception handler. As this is very situation-specific, something like the following should help get you started:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler to get
    # the request to work from
    response = exception_handler(exc)

    if isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
        # Always return a 422 status code for validation errors
       response.status = 422

    return response
```

In your case, you would be triggering a new exception instead of changing the status code of the response.

Comment: how would I know my custom Exception "userNotAuthenticatedError" will reach all way to exception_handler if it is not a `ValidationError`

Comment: You're looking to raise the custom exception within the exception handler. Last line of the answer: `In your case, you would be triggering a new exception instead of changing the status code of the response.`